# Replace mathematical expression only in Texmaker editor

Tags: texmaker

Thank you all. I want to ,for example, replace the letter L by `$\ell$`  `only in the mathematical expression` in Texmaker.

Suppose the document is large. I don't want to do it manually. Is there some trick?
here is the document:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
Let $3>L>1$ then $\frac{1}{3}<\frac{1}{L}<1$

Let M , N and L be points in the complex plane
\end{document}
```

many thanks

Comment: do you really use latin1? `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` for example any example posted to this site is not `latin` but `utf-8` (which is the default encoding in latex)

Comment: Off topic, but the final sentence should be `Let $M$, $N$, and $L$ be points in the complex plane.` because those points are math.  Which then makes it kind of on topic, because now `$L$` will be `$\ell$`.

Comment: @Teepeemm , I agree with you, but I deliberately did that to make it clear that if I press `Control + G`  and type `L `in  above place and `\ell `in the below place , it replaces` every L`, and this is what I, of course, do not want.

Comment: Whether the point L should be typeset as math is a different question than if it should be typeset as L or \ell.  I agree that you don't want `\ellet every ...` which is what you would get with a naive find-and-replace-all.  But the point L is math, and should be typeset as such.  So I'm not quite sure how you agree with me.

Comment: To convey the idea correctly, I will assume the content of the document is:
Let $3>L>1$ then $\frac{1}{3}<\frac{1}{L}<1$ . L is the twelfth letter of the English language.

Comment: I posted an answer but I would not use it. Surely any editor has a query-replace option where you replace L by `\ell ` but hit a yes/no key for each instance. How many capital L do you have? I would have thought you could replave all the math L in a document in a couple of minutes in less keystrokes than it takes to write this question?

Answer (score 3):

You can tell TeX to typeset a Math L as an ell

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\mathcode`L=\ell
\begin{document}
Let $3>L>1$ then $\frac{1}{3}<\frac{1}{L}<1$

Let M , N and L be points in the complex plane
\end{document}
```

[image]